# how to show blob image in html?

Tags: php, html

I have a image stored in mysql as mediumblob and now I want to show it in html page, so I am doing this with it:

```
$c = base64_encode($resu[0]->image);
$image = '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$c.'" />';
echo $image;
```

But I am getting only half of original image, so am I missing something here ?

Comment: Are you sure, that `$resu[0]->image` contains the full image? How have you verified this?

Comment: how can I verify it ? I echoed it and it shows data and the blob column of mysql displays correct size

Comment: What's the size of the original file? What's the size of the data in your blob column?

Comment: I checked it with strlen and its much higher then blob column ie: 1 row has 44kb and $resu has 60288 byte(58kb) for that

Comment: Please stop copy and paste and answer the questions.

Comment: I dont want to offend you omeinusch, I just want your attention for my previous comments, If you do not wish to help me then Its your decision. Thanks for reading/trying to solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea, may be you can seperate the logic to display the image.
What I mean is that you can create a file like image.php that accepts the id or filename
of the image and then display the image. Then you can simply refer the image in your HTML
by, for example, doing something like this:

```
<img src="image.php?imgId=12547"/>
```

in **image.php** file something like the following

```
$imgId=isset(GET['imgId'])?GET['imgId']:0;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM theBlogs WHERE ID = $imgId;";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());  
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $row['imageContent'];
```

Comment: thanks for your inputs, but it is not possible with my problem because I am working in wordpress plugin development

Comment: Sorry, then probably I would not be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just perform a quick test with `strlen` on `$resu[0]->image` variable and check blob size in DB and check if they are different sizes for sure.

Comment: I checked it with strlen and its much higher then blob column ie: 1 column has 44kb and $resu has 60288 byte(58kb) for that.

Answer (score 0):

Display in li tag means use this
    `<li data-thumb='<?php echo "data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($img1 ); ?>'>
    <div class="thumb-image"> 
    <img <?php echo 'src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $img1 ).'"';?>
        data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive" alt=""> 
    </div>
    </li>`